# How do I stop gnome's disk-utility from spamming me with disk error messages until my X session freezes?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

I have a headless computer running ubuntu 11.04 with metacity. I vnc into it every now and again. It has a failing disk attached which I am trying to get some data off.

Every now and again a friendly message comes up titled "Disk Utility" saying "Hard disk problems detected" and giving me the option to "Examine", "Ok" or "Cancel" (cool, did not know I could just cancel my hard disk problems).

This is useful the first time but it comes up a lot. So often in fact that the next morning my X session has usually been rendered unusable because so many of these dialog windows have popped up.

I don't really consider this a usability win. How can I disable it?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/76781/how-to-stop-ubuntu-9-10-from-showing-hard-disk-failing-notification

Comment: duplicate:http://superuser.com/questions/76781/how-to-stop-ubuntu-9-10-from-showing-hard-disk-failing-notification/727853

Answer (score 2):

Over [here](https://superuser.com/a/78962/57828), Styrke said:

1. Open the Disk Utility from System > Administration > Disk Utility (or maybe a click on the warning will open it?)
2. Choose the disk that is failing and click the More Information link. (The link is placed to the red text that is showing you the warning)
3. Set a mark in the Don't warn me if the disk is failing-checkbox just above the attributes in the bottom of the window.

Worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

If your disk is failing, better just not run any GUI (especially remotely). Just backup what you can, preferably after booting from other medium (like livecd or another disk). Then either repair it using disk manufacturer's dedicated software or take apart and make use of the nice, strong magnets ;)

Comment: The disk is not my system disk. Backing up what I can is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Oh, I see. But the main advise still holds: just do not run GUI - start the system in console mode and use `cp -a` or `tar` or `dd`.

Comment: I find it kind of ironic that with all this harping on about Freedom in linux systems I am apparently not free to use my failing disk.

Comment: Now **that** is some argument... So with all the harping on how America is a Free Country, you cannot drive your broken car! (Or have to push it yourself.)

Comment: I believe I would be entitled to drive my broken down car (or push it myself) on my own property.

Comment: Car analogy is always bad, so please don' use them.
Yes, you can use your system as you want, if you know what you are doing.  To take a car analogy, you can repair your modern all electric car if you like, but it will be expensive and your warent will not hold if you do something wrong.  :-)